# Content assist broken in Eclipse Mars 2?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I have written the word

`Preferences`

and after that word, standing with the cursor after the `s`, I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

What I expect is that an import should be added, namely

```
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;
```

The actual outcome is that nothing happens.

Why?

Comment: Is the project a Java project? Look in Window -> Preferences and in the Java -> Editor -> Content Assist and verify that it's enabled; then check to see if the "Java Proposals" is selected.

Comment: If I right click the project node in Package Explorer and choose properties, I see that its Type: Project, not java project. I thought I had a java project? It compiles files properly. I can set source folders etc. And also run the project... Java ->  Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced shows the checkboxes, but even when I am checking the box "Java Proposals", the functionality in question will not be enabled.

Comment: "Type: Project" is normal. You can tell it's a Java project if it has a little J on the folder icon in the project explorer and/or if you can actually run/compile it. So it sounds like that part of it is fine. Must be a problem in how your content assist is configured though since I can not reproduce the problem locally (I get a import suggestion just fine).

Comment: I now get the red "No completions available" text in the bottom left corner when I use ctrl+space.